Calculate all missing values for specific data using pivot tables in pandas
I am working on this dataset called titanic.csv Let's simplify the problem and include some data here:

I need to calculate all missing values for child, as you see it is a value under who column. This should be done using a pivot table.
I have tried this solution:
pd.pivot_table(df[df['who'] == 'child'], 
index='sex', 
aggfunc=lambda x: x.isnull().sum(), 
 margins=True) # to sum all missing values based on gender

But I get this output: 
in which as you also notice, ALL row doesn't sum all missing values per gender.
Where is the problem in my code? Should I use another way to create the pivot table?

Here you find a smaller dataset to reproduce your code:
data = {     'survived': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],     'pclass': [3, 1, 3, 1, 3],     'sex': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male'],     'age': [22, 38, 6, 35, 35],     'class': ['Third', 'First', 'Third', 'First', 'Third'],     'who': ['man', 'woman', 'child', 'child', 'man'],     'deck': [None, 'C', None, 'C', None],     'alive': ['no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'],     'alone': [False, False, True, False, True] }

Please show the output you expect using your smaller sample dataset. Note that this and the sample data are best edited into the question rather than given in comments,

@user19077881 the output I need is no different from the output provided. But as you notice in the last column ALL should sum 33+37 missing value and report 70, not 0. This is why I included margins. Why doesn’t perform so? What should I change in my code?

EDIT:
If you prefer to use a pivot table, just add the parameter dropna=False to get the result you want.

First answer:
If you want the number of missing values per features for only the child you can use isna/isnull directly after filtering:
data = {'survived': [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
        'pclass': [3, 1, None, 1, 3], 
        'sex': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'female', 'male'], 
        'age': [22, 38, None, None, 35], 
        'class_': ['Third', 'First', None, 'First', 'Third'], 
        'who': ['man', 'woman', 'child', 'child', 'man'], 
        'deck': [None, 'C', None, 'C', None], 
        'alive': ['no', 'yes', 'yes', 'yes', 'no'], 
        'alone': [False, False, True, False, True] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

display(df[df["who"] == "child"].isna().sum())

survived    0
pclass      1
sex         0
age         2
class_      1
who         0
deck        1
alive       0
alone       0


Thank you for your answer but it doesn’t answer my question. I need necessarily to create a pivot table, as also written in the question title.

Ok, I edited my answer.

Well now it responds my question

This question would be solved by also changing index to 'who' and removing margins parameter as not needed.
pd.pivot_table(df[df['who'] == 'child'], 
    index = 'who', 
    aggfunc = lambda x: x.isnull().sum())

